# A pipe pattern using templates instead of virtual methods

Tags: c++, templates, adapter

I'm trying to create the pipe pattern without virtual methods, so that an object of class `C` will call a method of object class `B`, will call a method of object class `A`, ... (and in reverse through a different method)

If this worked, then it would function like a pipe pattern, with `StartChain::next` calling `C::next` calling `B::next` calling `A::next` calling `EndChain::next`, and with the `prev`s going from `EndChain::prev` -> `StartChain::prev` through the different structures.

However- I can not figure out the correct syntax to allow this to happen.

```
template<typename P>
struct EndChain
{
    P *p;
    void next ()
    {
    }

    void prev ()
    {
        p->prev();
    }
} ;

template<typename N, typename P>
struct A
{
    N *n;
    P *p;

    void next ()
    {
        n->next();
    }

    void prev ()
    {
        p->prev();
    }
} ;

template<typename N, typename P>
struct B
{
    N *n;
    P *p;

    void next ()
    {
        n->next();
    }

    void prev ()
    {
        p->prev();
    }
} ;

template<typename N, typename P>
struct C
{
    N *n;
    P *p;

    void next ()
    {
        n->next();
    }

    void prev ()
    {
        p->prev();
    }
} ;

template<typename N>
struct StartChain
{
    N *n;
    void next ()
    {
        n->next();
    }

    void prev ()
    {
    }
} ;
```

as `using Chain = StartChain<C<B<A<EndChain<B<A< ...` obviously doesn't work.

Comment: CRTP to the rescue?

Comment: I don't think CRTP solves this.

Comment: This isn't really the adapter pattern, because that's usually one-way. This is a pipeline, and it's much easier if the pipeline container handles traversal instead of making each stage invoke the next.

Comment: @Useless .  I think you are correct.  I should change the title of the question.  I will attempt to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was... a journey. I even had to take a break and come back to actually understand what I just wrote.

The idea is that each pipeline node (`A`, `B`, `C`) is a class template with one type parameter. This parameter contains information about the whole pipeline, and is a policy from which the node class must also inherit. Since we don't want to get trapped in an infinite recursion, we handle node types around as templates, without instantiating them until necessary (which is in phase 2 lookup, where everything has been defined properly). Let's go:

First we define a set of tools, some simple metafunctions:

```
// Stores a class template to be instantiated later
template <template <class...> class T>
struct tlift {
    // Instantiate the template
    template <class... Args>
    using apply = T<Args...>;
};

// Identity function
template <class T>
struct identity {
    using type = T;
};
```

... and a pack of class templates with its set of functions:

```
// Pack of class templates
template <template <class> class...>
struct tpack { };

// Get the Nth element
template <class Pack, std::size_t N>
struct tpack_at;

template <template <class> class P0, template <class> class... P, std::size_t N>
struct tpack_at<tpack<P0, P...>, N> : tpack_at<tpack<P...>,  N - 1> { };

template <template <class> class P0, template <class> class... P>
struct tpack_at<tpack<P0, P...>, 0> {
    using type = tlift<P0>;
};

// Get the size of the pack
template <class Pack>
struct tpack_size;

template <template <class> class... P>
struct tpack_size<tpack<P...>>
: std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(P)> { };
```

Note that, as templates cannot be exposed bare, `tpack_at` returns a `tlift` containing the actual template.

Then comes the meat of the solution: the policy class, unoriginally named `Context`. First things first, we poke around to know who our neighbours are:

```
// Base class and template parameter for pipeline nodes
template <class Pipeline, std::size_t Index>
struct Context {

    // Type of the previous node, or void if none exists
    using Prev = typename std::conditional_t<
        Index == 0,
        identity<tlift<std::void_t>>,
        tpack_at<Pipeline, Index - 1>
    >::type::template apply<Context<Pipeline, Index - 1>>;

    // Type of the next node, or void if none exists
    using Next = typename std::conditional_t<
        Index == tpack_size<Pipeline>::value - 1,
        identity<tlift<std::void_t>>,
        tpack_at<Pipeline, Index + 1>
    >::type::template apply<Context<Pipeline, Index + 1>>;
```

Each of these somewhat convoluted typedefs checks whether we're the first (resp. last) node in the pipeline, then retrieves a `tlift` containing our previous (resp. next) node. This `tlift` is then unwrapped with the `Pipeline` and neighbouring `Index` we already have, to produce the complete node type. If this neighbour doesn't exist, the `tlift` contains `std::void_t`, which will just ignore its parameters upon unwrapping and return `void`.

Once this type gymnastic is done, we can store two pointers for our two neighbours:

```
private:
    Prev *_prev;
    Next *_next;
```

Note: the first and last `Context`s each contain an unused `void *` to their non-existing neighbour. I haven't taken the time to optimize them out, but that could be done as well.

Then we implement two functions which will be inherited by the node, and allow it to call `prev` and `next` on its neighbours. Since it didn't add complexity, and I needed a template for the `if constexpr` anyway, I added argument forwarding into the mix:

```
// Call the previous node's prev() function with arguments
template <class... Args>
void callPrev(Args &&... args) {
    if constexpr(!std::is_void_v<Prev>)
        _prev->prev(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// Call the next node's next() function with arguments
template <class... Args>
void callNext(Args &&... args) {
    if constexpr(!std::is_void_v<Next>)
        _next->next(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Finally, `Context`'s constructor expects a reference to the tuple of all nodes, and will pick its neighbours from within:

```
// Construction from the actual tuple of nodes
template <class... T>
Context(std::tuple<T...> &pipeline) {
    if constexpr(std::is_void_v<Prev>)  _prev = nullptr;
    else                                _prev = &std::get<Index - 1>(pipeline);

    if constexpr(std::is_void_v<Next>)  _next = nullptr;
    else                                _next = &std::get<Index + 1>(pipeline);
}
```

The only thing left to do is to wrap the weird initialization we need into a maker function:

```
template <template <class> class... Nodes, std::size_t... Idx>
auto make_pipeline(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    using Pack = tpack<Nodes...>;
    std::tuple<Nodes<Context<Pack, Idx>>...> pipeline{{((void)Idx, pipeline)}...}; // (1)
    return pipeline;
}

template <template <class Context> class... Nodes>
auto make_pipeline() {
    return make_pipeline<Nodes...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Nodes)>{});
}
```

Note the recursion point at `(1)`, where `pipeline` will pass its own reference to the constructors of the various nodes so they can each forward it to their `Context`. The `((void)Idx, pipeline)` trick is to have the expression depend on a template parameter pack so I can actually pack-expand it.

Finally, a node can be defined this way:

```
template <class Context>
struct NodeA : Context {
    // Forward the context's constructor, or implement yours
    using Context::Context;

    void prev() {
        // Do something
        Context::callPrev();
    }

    void next() {
        // Do something
        Context::callNext();
    }
};
```

... and usage looks like:

```
int main() {
    auto pipeline = make_pipeline<NodeA, NodeB, NodeC>();

    std::get<0>(pipeline).next(); // Calls the whole chain forward
    std::get<2>(pipeline).prev(); // Calls the whole chain backwards
}
```

Note that the pointers within the pipeline remain valid, thanks to the copy elision taking place when returning from `make_pipeline`. You should not, however, copy it further (correct copy prevention left as an exercise).

That's all, folks. [See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7aa589b105fafdc1)

Comment: Thanks to copy elision guaranty, there are no dangling pointers with `make_pipeline()`. :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 yep, this escaped my head on the way. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, once we have a pipeline (`tuple`), gymnastic with `next`/`prev` seems superfluous -> `std::apply([](auto... nodes){ (nodes.do_job(), ...); }, pipeline)`. `prev` requires a little more work with `std::make_index_sequence`.

Comment: @Jarod42 definitely, or with an actual container as well. Just wanted to grind my angle brackets on this particular idea ;)

Comment: @Quentin: Simplified version added as answer for info.

Answer (score 2):

Using a full pipeline as Quentin answered is the way to go.
but then `prev`/`next` seems superfluous to your usage, and code can then be simplified.

```
template <typename ... Nodes>
class pipeline
{
public:
    explicit pipeline(const std::tuple<Nodes...>& nodes) : nodes(nodes) {}

    template <typename ... Ts>
    void traverse(Ts&&... args) {
        std::apply([&](auto&&... flatNodes){ (flatNodes(args...), ...); }, nodes);
    }

    template <typename ... Ts>
    void rev_traverse(Ts&&... args) {
        rev_traverse_impl(std::index_sequence_for<Nodes...>(), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

private:
    template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
    void rev_traverse_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts&&...args)
    {
        constexpr auto size = sizeof...(Nodes);

        (std::get<size - 1 - Is>(nodes)(args...), ...);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Nodes...> nodes;
};
```

With node similar to:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(/*...*/);
    void operator()() const { /*..*/ }     
};
```

and usage:

```
pipeline<A, B, B, C> p({A{}, B{0}, B{1}, C{}});

p.traverse(); 
p.rev_traverse();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a587320a8a3b0ef8)

Or even use lambda:

```
pipeline p(std::tuple(A{}, B{0}, B{1}, [](){ std::cout << "Lambda"; }));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c3d2efc3bc61a28)

Comment: This is a really awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we could instantiate those templates how you want to, e.g. of `Start` -> `A` -> `End`.

In the middle, we will need an instantiation of `A`, specifically

```
A<Start<*>, End<*>>
```

Except that we don't have the type to put in `*`, as that is the type we are trying to instantiate. We have a recursive definition without a base case.

What you are asking for is not expressible in C++ types